# Long layover in London with change in airport

Tags: luggage, lhr, connecting-flights, british-airways, lgw

I have a flight from Mumbai to Toronto with British Airways with a 18 hr layover in London where I also have to change airports. My itinerary looks like this (all times are local):

BOM-LHR dep on 30th May 2019 at 13:10

LGW-YYZ dep on 31st May 2019 at 12:55

Will my check in bags be available directly at Toronto or will they need to be collected at LHR and checked in again next day at LGW? Please note that this is on a single PNR.

Comment: We will be able to help you better if we have your arrival time for London Heathrow, (LHR) as the length of the stay in London might be too short for the transfer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

British Airways [states](https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/airport-information/flight-connections) that your baggage will not be transferred between Heathrow and Gatwick and that you must do this yourself.

> Your baggage will not be automatically forwarded so please **collect all your bags** before leaving Heathrow or Gatwick airport.

When you check in at Mumbai your bags will be checked to Heathrow. You will need to collect them at baggage reclaim after immigration, then check them in again with a BA agent at Gatwick for the remainder of your trip to Toronto.

Comment: Also worth noting that a visa might be required for this transfer, depending on nationalities et al involved.

Comment: If you are travelling to/from Canada/US/Australia, you can avail visa free entry into the UK provided you depart by air and your flight departs within 24 hours.

Comment: @BhushanKale are you sure about that? It's not mentioned on [gov.uk's page on Visa to pass through the UK in transit](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa). It does explicitly mention needing a short term visa for *'changing flights in the UK on your way to another country'* and *'go through UK border control, for example to check in your luggage for a connecting flight'* (among other things). Specifically, I think you need a *Visitor in Transit visa*.

Comment: @JJJ See [here](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/yes). It's actually _before midnight the following day_, rather than just 24 hours.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yea, but it says *"might"* and *"You won’t be able to transit without a visa if a Border Force officer decides you don’t qualify under the immigration rules."*

Comment: Sorry for a really late remark. I did avail this facility last year. Although the visa officer was reluctant in granting me a visa, said they only grant this visa to people who are stranded at the airport due to flight cancellations or delays or other involuntary reasons. She ultimately issued me one, but be careful.